# Setting an HTML form's custom enctype?

Tags: html, forms, serialization

Say I have an HTML form:

```
<form action="/whatever" enctype="application/x-custom" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar"/>
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to provide a custom `enctype` algorithm to the browser? Suppose the algorithm is:

```
<script>
function algo(/** HTMLFormElement */form) {
return Array
    .from(form.elements)
    .filter(e => e.type === 'hidden')
    .map(e => e.name.length + ';' + e.value.length + ';' + e.name + e.value)
    .join("\n");
}
</script>
```

Is there a way I can "bind" this algorithm to the form so that *the browser* follows it to serialise the form data and send the form request with `Content-Type: application/x-custom` and the algorithm's result as the request body?

I'm not looking for a "Use XMLHttpRequest" answer, I'm only looking for browser-based form submission with a custom form data serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately if you want to send the data in custom format, you will have to send it via AJAX. I had to do this several times, it's not at all trivial. Your code would fail with things like `<input type="checkbox>`, `<select>`, `disabled` inputs and many others.

As far as sending the data, assuming to manage to get the data right, you'd want to send via fetch:

```
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} form
 */
function algo(form) {
    return Array
        .from(form.elements)
        .filter(e => e.type === 'hidden')
        .map(e => e.name.length + ';' + e.value.length + ';' + e.name + e.value)
        .join("\n");
}
/**
 * 
 * @param {HTMLFormElement} form
 */
async function postData(form) {

    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(form.action, {
        method: 'POST',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-custom',
        },
        redirect: 'follow',
        body: algo(form)
    });
    window.history.pushState(null, "", form.action);
    // this is nasty, but emulates form response nicely
    // do not actually do this
    document.open();
    document.write(await response.text());
    document.close();
}
```

Alternatively, have a server-side handler that converts received form data to the correct format.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of :/ That's a nice idea to use fetch too, even tho that's still JS-driven navigation somehow.